# Terminating a user input determined Scanner?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I wonder if someone could explain why the scanner keeps waiting on input? I have to stop the process on eclipse before the code block executes and I am unsure why the scanner will **keep taking input all day**. I expect to press enter and for the code to execute after entering X amount of numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter Ints : ");         
    while(aScanner.hasNextInt()){
        sum += aScanner.nextInt(); 
    }       
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the program to take only X amount of numbers, you could have a counter and break the while loop after it has executed X number of times. Alternatively, you could also use a for loop to make things easier.

You could also use Ctrl+Z in eclipse to stop console from waiting for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest** way to solve it is:

- Enter the "end of file" marker, by the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> in UNIX, if I'm not wrong).

Another way would be using a centinel value tu finish the `while` loop:

```
Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0, input = 0;

System.out.println("Enter Ints (-999 to finish input): ");
while ((input = aScanner.nextInt()) != -999) {
    sum += input;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

so the input will finish when the user enters `-999`, of course you can change this value.

**Note:**

- The last approach won't work if you expect *any* integer (including negatives and extrene values) as input.